# mysql query to return related rows

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql table ref_table with fields

```
node_id
topic_id
ref_id
```

Ref_id's refer to the actual objects being stored. There may be an arbitrary number of rows with the same ref_id, and different combinations of node_id and topic_id. 
I now have a need to retrieve all distinct node_id values for which a record (node_id, ref_id=A) exists, subject to the constraint that a record exists for (NODE_ID, TOPIC_ID, ref_id=A) - where NODE_ID and TOPIC_ID are my variable parameters. 
In other words, I'm trying to find all the objects that have a particular combination of NODE_ID and TOPIC_ID, and then return all the nodes in which this object appears. Seems simple enough, but I can't wrap my head around the query syntax to do it. It's OK if the query returns NODE_ID itself.

It would be even better if the query could return a list of node_id's along with the number of times the node_id was found to match.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT r2.node_id, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM ref_table r1
    INNER JOIN ref_table r2 ON r1.ref_id = r2.ref_id
WHERE r1.node_id = [node]
    AND r1.topic_id = [topic]
GROUP BY r2.node_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that works. Meanwhile, I had come up with a different solution myself (see below). Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: The query above will almost surely be faster, because it doesn't involve a sub-query. However, try running them the both and observing the results.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
select node_id, count(*) as c from ref_table 
where topic_id=[topic] 
and node_id in (select distinct node_id from ref_table where node_id=[node] and topic_id=[topic])
group by node_id;
```